# Error while listing all endpoints in Micronaut app (using /routes endpoint)

Tags: java, micronaut

I have this sample [hello world](https://github.com/yassirez-znafry/sample-micronaut-app) project in micronaut. After I added the *micronaut-management* dependency, I tried to enter to http://localhost:8080/routes to see all my endpoints. but It shows me *This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 401*.
Steps to reproduce:
1- Create a micronaut project using https://micronaut.io/launch , (Java 8 and maven).
2- Add the *micronaut-management* dependency to the pom.xml .
3- run the application and enter to http://localhost:8080/routes .

Comment: See https://github.com/yassirez-znafry/sample-micronaut-app/pull/1

Comment: yes that solved the problem... Thanks @JeffScottBrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 401 -> Unauthorized access.

Micronaut has sensitivity feature, all management urls sensitivity are enable by default.

For /routes, following configuration can be added into application.properties to allow the /routes url access.

```
endpoints.routes.sensitive=false
```

Comment: "following configuration can be added into application.properties" - Can also be added to other config sources like `application.yml`.  The PR at https://github.com/yassirez-znafry/sample-micronaut-app/pull/1 does that.